# cant connect to facebook with a network thread

Tags: java, android, facebook, multithreading

I need to connect to facebook so I use a Tread when using the network. but I have a problem:

```
 Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                    FacebookConnectTask task = new FacebookConnectTask("facebookId", "token", "email", facebookGender,0, 0);

                    task.setOnPreExecuteListener(this);
                    task.setOnDoneListener(this);

                    task.execute();
                }
    });
    t.start();

}
```

I cant do

```
task.setOnPreExecuteListener(this);
task.setOnDoneListener(this);
```

eclipse gives me this error: **"The method setOnDoneListener(Task.OnDoneListener) in the type Task is not applicable for the arguments (new Runnable(){})"**

How can i fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: what is _setOnDoneListener_ signature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've changed context's by being in a Thread your in an Annoyomous class, `this` is now your annonomous class and not the outer class.

Try this (pun intended):

```
 task.setOnPreExecuteListener(YourOuterClass.this);
 task.setOnDoneListener(YourOuterClass.this);
```

i.e.

```
public class YourClass implements OnDoneListener {

    public doFacebook(){

      new Thread(new Runnable(){
         @Override
         public void run(){
              task.setOnDoneListener(YourClass.this);
         }
      }.start();

    }


    @Override
    public void onDone(){

    }

}
```

or alternatively pull your Threaded class out:

```
public class DoSomething implements Runnable {

       private final OnDoneListener listener;

       public DoSomething(OnDoneListener listener){
            this.listener = listener;
       }

       @Override
       public void run(){
            FacebookConnectTask task = ... ;

            task.setOnDoneListener(listener);
       }


}

public class YourActivity extends Activity implements OnDoneListener {

     public void onCreate(Bundle b){
          new Thread(new DoSomething(this)).start();
     }

     @Override
     public void onDone(){
        // Tada
     }

}
```

A further step if you wanted to be cooler is create your own interface and keep all the Facebook stuff in the runnable class:

```
 public class DoSomething implements Runnable, OnDoneListener {

       public interface OnFacebookFinished {
              void onFacebookFinished();
       }

       private final OnFacebookFinished listener;

       public DoSomething(OnFacebookFinished listener){
            this.listener = listener;
       }

       @Override
       public void run(){
            FacebookConnectTask task = ... ;

            task.setOnDoneListener(this);
       }

       @Override
       public void onDone(){
           if(listener != null){
               listener.onFacebookFinished();
           }
       }


}

public class YourActivity extends Activity implements OnFacebookFinished {

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle b){
          new Thread(new DoSomething(this)).start();
     }

     @Override
     public void onFacebookFinished(){
        // Tada
     }

}
```

Comment: @roiberg which did you go for? :-)